# php code inside a href tag not working

Tags: php

I would like to redirect to other pages but the `=` sign isn't working, the page name, the title, and the id are coming from database. I tried putting `.` before the `=` but that doesn't work. I think this should be simple but couldn't figure it out. can someone help me out?

```
 echo  "<a href=".$row['page']=.$row['topic']."& id=".$row['id'].">".click here."</a>";
```

Comment: @RishabhRaj `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'` before row topic.

Comment: thats because you are not properly using the "" and''.i think somebody already answered this so go through the answer of @hcoat .i executed his code and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
echo "<a href='".$row['page']."=".$row['topic']."&id=".$row['id']."'>click here</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

`echo  '<a href="' . $row['page'] . '=' . $row['topic'] . '&id=' . $row['id'] . '">click here</a>';`

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing a few quotes and dots. This will work.

```
echo  "<a href='".$row['page']."=".$row['topic']."&id=".$row['id']."'>click here</a>";
```